# Whisker menu missing

Tags: xubuntu

I installed `xubuntu-desktop` using `tasksel` on top of my default Ubuntu unity, but I can't find where the XFCE menu is. Here is a picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) I'm sorry and, please, blame it on me: I'm confused and confusing...  But...  *What's your question???* :/  Please visit the [Ask Ubuntu Tour](http://askubuntu.com/tour) to better understand how this site works, as it is quite different from a forum...

Comment: @Fabby It seems clear enough to me. He installed xubuntu-desktop through taskel but the "xfce menu" isn't there (as you can see in the screenshot).

Comment: @Seth: Close vote retracted...  But I wasn't the only one that didn't understand "whisker" apparently.  Question edited...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The XFCE-Menu you are talking about is called `xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin`. It is a plugin that lives in a xfce4 panel. So make sure you have xfce4 and the whiskermenu installed.

## Check if Whisker Menu is installed

#### Ubuntu Software Center way

Go into the ubuntu software center and check if whisker menu is installed searching for it and see if there is a green check mark. If not install it.

#### Terminal way

Check if whiskermenu is installed

```
dpkg -s xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
```

If not installed install it

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
```

## Add Whisker Menu to your XFCE4 Panel

If you have installed the package properly you should be able to add it to an xfce4 panel.

1. Right click the bar you have in your screenshot
2. Click `Panel`
3. Click `Add New Items..`
4. Search for whisker in your items and add it

Whiskermenu should appear now in your panel.

## Edit Whisker Menu

If you want to edit the whiskermenu you need the package `menulibre` which is also available in the software center.

Installing it works like above

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

or via the Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Improve your answer: You could add the commands for the terminal.

Comment: All the steps necessary to do this were already in in the answer. To do all this you don't need the terminal. But ok.. added the commands.

Comment: BINGO! Add to panel step helped save me a lot of time.